# Jupyter Notebook doesnt launch when I click on it from Start

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe on Windows 7. It was working fine like Launching Jupyter Notebbok & navigator through Mozilla.

But I had to uninstall this and install it again due to some reason. I have updated PATH variable to take all the required paths as per google. But It is not launching the Jupyter notebook/Navigator from Start menu now. However Python is launching from Anaconda Prompt in the same black window.

Can you please help how to open Jupyter notebook?
Below is the error when I try to open it from Anaconda prompt.

```
(base) PS C:\> jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rr814q\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebo
ok-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\rr814q\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\note
book\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Users\rr814q\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torn
ado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\rr814q\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98,
in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

1. `activate base` (run as administration the cmd/powershell if needed), then run `jupyter notebook` or `python -m notebook`
2. Add `anaconda3` folder to your `$PATH`.
3. Run this `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` and try again method 1.

Good luck!